# Можно ли сделать чтобы if сравнивала не с одним словом, а с множеством слов?

Tags: javascript, if, discord

Например:

```
const Qw = "<@!000000000000000000> "

if(message.content.startsWith(Qw + '1', '2', '3')) {
   message.channel.send("test");
};
```

Я хочу чтобы я боту написал любую из указанных трех цифр и он мне написал "test", возможно ли такое сделать, если поможете найти решение этой сложной для меня задачи, буду благодарен !?

Comment: Если я вас правильно понимаю, то вам нужно вот это :
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes

Comment: @EugeneKuznetsov , Спасибо. Работает, а можно ли как-то сделать чтоб он брал слова для сравнение не из const, а из файла txt ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
if (message.startsWith(Qw)) {
  message = message.slice(Qw.length, message.length);
  // Базовая проверка
  if (!message) return;
  let args = message.trim().split(' ');
  if (['1', '2', '3'].includes(args[0])) {
    return message.channel.send("test");
  }
}
```